# What is this mysterious jq failures?

Tags: jq

I have seen this issue. I guess it’s related to special char. I’ve read the jq manual and quote the field but still fail, I tried both with/without the bracket

```
abc@uswest1aprod 13:49:59 ~
   $ cat test | jq .
{
  "bus_v320161103-12-00-44": {
    "aliases": {
      "bus_v3": {}
   },
    "mappings": {
      "business": {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
abc@uswest1aprod 13:52:33 ~
   $ cat test | jq ."bus_v320161103-12-00-44"
jq: error: null and number cannot be subtracted
abc@uswest1aprod 13:53:09 ~
   $ cat test | jq .["bus_v320161103-12-00-44"]
error: bus_v320161103 is not defined
.[bus_v320161103-12-00-44]  1 compile error
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote your filter so it isn't interpreted by the shell...

```
$ jq '."bus_v320161103-12-00-44"' test
```

Without it, it's effectively being passed in like this:

```
.bus_v320161103-12-00-44
```

Which is accessing a field called `bus_v320161103` and subtracting that by `12`, then `00` then `44`.